# How can I use multipal group by and sort them by timestamp within multipal left joins?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, timestamp, left-join

I have been working on this code for my website's news feed for a while now.  I have the site setup where members can comment on comments.  Currently the news feed shows all comments members post on "main" comments.

I want to only show the most recent sub comment.  The area of the code where I am currently trying to get this working is "location_comments" and "location_comments_b".

Here is my complete code for recent post aka news feed.  It currently works but shows all "location_comments_b".

```
    <?
    unset($timestamp);
            if(isset($_GET['rc_view'])){ $rc_view = $_GET['rc_view']; }else{ $rc_view = ""; }

        //Check to see if user is logged in to display stats updates
        if(($userId = is_logged())!= 0)
        {


            //Check to see if user wants to see more posts    
            if(isset($_GET['offset'])){ $offset = $_GET['offset']; }

            //echo "($rc_view)";

            // no of elements per page 

            if(isset($offset)){
                $limitfriendstatus = "$offset";
            }else{
                $limitfriendstatus = "10"; 
            }

            require "pages/my/status/commentnew.inc";
            echo "<br>";

    $q_status = "
    (SELECT status.timestamp, status.id, status.com_uid, status.com_name, status.com_content, status.com_id, friend.userId1, friend.userId2, friend.status1, friend.status2, 
    'status' AS post_type FROM status
    LEFT JOIN friend
    ON (status.com_id = friend.userId1 AND friend.userId2 = $userIdme)
    OR (status.com_id = friend.userId2 AND friend.userId1 = $userIdme)
    WHERE friend.status1 = '1' AND friend.status2 = '1'
    OR status.com_id = '$userIdme'
    GROUP BY status.id)
    ";

    $q_status_com = "
    (SELECT statcom.timestamp, statcom.id, statcom.statcom_uid, statcom.statcom_name, statcom.statcom_content, statcom.statcom_id, friend.userId1, friend.userId2, friend.status1, friend.status2, 
    'statcom' AS post_type FROM statcom
    LEFT JOIN friend
    ON (statcom.statcom_uid = friend.userId1 AND friend.userId2 = $userIdme)
    OR (statcom.statcom_uid = friend.userId2 AND friend.userId1 = $userIdme)
    WHERE friend.status1 = '1' AND friend.status2 = '1'
    OR statcom.statcom_uid = '$userIdme'
    GROUP BY statcom.id)
    ";

    $s_status = "
    (SELECT sweet.timestamp, sweet.sid, sweet.sweet_location, sweet.sweet_sec_id, sweet.sweet_owner_userid, sweet.sweet_userid, friend.userId1, friend.userId2, friend.status1, friend.status2,
    'sweet' AS post_type FROM sweet
    LEFT JOIN friend
    ON (sweet.sweet_userid = friend.userId1 AND friend.userId2 = $userIdme)
    OR (sweet.sweet_userid = friend.userId2 AND friend.userId1 = $userIdme)
    WHERE ( friend.status1 = '1' AND friend.status2 = '1'
    OR sweet.sweet_userid = '$userIdme' )
    AND NOT sweet.sweet_location = 'status' AND NOT sweet.sweet_location = 'statuscom'
    AND NOT sweet.sweet_location = 'profilecomments_b' AND NOT sweet.sweet_location = 'writingcomments_b'
    AND NOT sweet.sweet_location = 'artcomments_b' AND NOT sweet.sweet_location = 'club_events_com' 
    AND NOT sweet.sweet_location = 'clubevent' AND NOT sweet.sweet_location = 'club_events_com_b' 
    AND NOT sweet.sweet_location = 'profilecomments' AND NOT sweet.sweet_location = 'clubcomments'
    AND NOT sweet.sweet_location = 'clubcomments_b' AND NOT sweet.sweet_location = 'artcomments'
    AND NOT sweet.sweet_location = 'writingcomments' AND NOT sweet.sweet_location = 'locations'
    AND NOT sweet.sweet_location = 'location_comments' AND NOT sweet.sweet_location = 'location_comments_b'   
    GROUP BY sweet.sid)
    ";

    $pc_status = "
    (SELECT profilecomments.timestamp, profilecomments.id, profilecomments.com_uid, profilecomments.com_name, profilecomments.com_content, profilecomments.com_id, friend.userId1, friend.userId2, friend.status1, friend.status2,
    'profilecomment' AS post_type FROM profilecomments
    LEFT JOIN friend
    ON (profilecomments.com_uid = friend.userId1 AND friend.userId2 = $userIdme)
    OR (profilecomments.com_uid = friend.userId2 AND friend.userId1 = $userIdme)
    WHERE friend.status1 = '1' AND friend.status2 = '1'
    OR profilecomments.com_uid = '$userIdme'
    GROUP BY profilecomments.id)
    ";

    $pc_statcom = "
    (SELECT profilecomments_b.timestamp, profilecomments_b.id, profilecomments_b.statcom_uid, profilecomments_b.statcom_name, profilecomments_b.statcom_content, profilecomments_b.statcom_id, friend.userId1, friend.userId2, friend.status1, friend.status2,
    'profilestatcom' AS post_type FROM profilecomments_b
    LEFT JOIN friend
    ON (profilecomments_b.statcom_uid = friend.userId1 AND friend.userId2 = $userIdme)
    OR (profilecomments_b.statcom_uid = friend.userId2 AND friend.userId1 = $userIdme)
    WHERE friend.status1 = '1' AND friend.status2 = '1'
    OR profilecomments_b.statcom_uid = '$userIdme'
    GROUP BY profilecomments_b.id)
    ";


    $vpc_status = "
    (SELECT writingcomments.timestamp, writingcomments.id, writingcomments.com_uid, writingcomments.com_name, writingcomments.com_content, writingcomments.com_id, friend.userId1, friend.userId2, friend.status1, friend.status2,
    'vpcom' AS post_type FROM writingcomments
    LEFT JOIN friend
    ON (writingcomments.com_uid = friend.userId1 AND friend.userId2 = $userIdme)
    OR (writingcomments.com_uid = friend.userId2 AND friend.userId1 = $userIdme)
    WHERE friend.status1 = '1' AND friend.status2 = '1'
    OR writingcomments.com_uid = '$userIdme'
    GROUP BY writingcomments.id)
    ";

    $vpc_statcom = "
    (SELECT writingcomments_b.timestamp, writingcomments_b.id, writingcomments_b.statcom_uid, writingcomments_b.statcom_name, writingcomments_b.statcom_content, writingcomments_b.statcom_id, friend.userId1, friend.userId2, friend.status1, friend.status2,
    'vpstatcom' AS post_type FROM writingcomments_b
    LEFT JOIN friend
    ON (writingcomments_b.statcom_uid = friend.userId1 AND friend.userId2 = $userIdme)
    OR (writingcomments_b.statcom_uid = friend.userId2 AND friend.userId1 = $userIdme)
    WHERE friend.status1 = '1' AND friend.status2 = '1'
    OR writingcomments_b.statcom_uid = '$userIdme'
    GROUP BY writingcomments_b.id)
    ";

    $art_status = "
    (SELECT artcomments.timestamp, artcomments.id, artcomments.com_uid, artcomments.com_name, artcomments.com_content, artcomments.com_id, friend.userId1, friend.userId2, friend.status1, friend.status2,
    'artcom' AS post_type FROM artcomments
    LEFT JOIN friend
    ON (artcomments.com_uid = friend.userId1 AND friend.userId2 = $userIdme)
    OR (artcomments.com_uid = friend.userId2 AND friend.userId1 = $userIdme)
    WHERE friend.status1 = '1' AND friend.status2 = '1'
    OR artcomments.com_uid = '$userIdme'
    GROUP BY artcomments.id)
    ";

    $art_statcom = "
    (SELECT artcomments_b.timestamp, artcomments_b.id, artcomments_b.statcom_uid, artcomments_b.statcom_name, artcomments_b.statcom_content, artcomments_b.statcom_id, friend.userId1, friend.userId2, friend.status1, friend.status2,
    'artstatcom' AS post_type FROM artcomments_b
    LEFT JOIN friend
    ON (artcomments_b.statcom_uid = friend.userId1 AND friend.userId2 = $userIdme)
    OR (artcomments_b.statcom_uid = friend.userId2 AND friend.userId1 = $userIdme)
    WHERE friend.status1 = '1' AND friend.status2 = '1'
    OR artcomments_b.statcom_uid = '$userIdme'
    GROUP BY artcomments_b.id)
    ";

    //Checks for location comments
    $location_status = "
    (SELECT location_comments.timestamp, location_comments.id, location_comments.com_uid, location_comments.com_name, location_comments.com_content, location_comments.com_id, friend.userId1, friend.userId2, friend.status1, friend.status2,
    'loc_com' AS post_type FROM location_comments
    LEFT JOIN friend
    ON (location_comments.com_uid = friend.userId1 AND friend.userId2 = $userIdme)
    OR (location_comments.com_uid = friend.userId2 AND friend.userId1 = $userIdme)
    WHERE friend.status1 = '1' AND friend.status2 = '1'
    OR location_comments.com_uid = '$userIdme'
    GROUP BY location_comments.id)
    ";

    //Checks for location comments comments aka b
    $location_status_b = "
    (SELECT location_comments_b.timestamp, location_comments_b.id, location_comments_b.statcom_uid, location_comments_b.statcom_name, location_comments_b.statcom_content, location_comments_b.statcom_id, friend.userId1, friend.userId2, friend.status1, friend.status2,
    'loc_com_b' AS post_type FROM location_comments_b
    LEFT JOIN friend
    ON (location_comments_b.statcom_uid = friend.userId1 AND friend.userId2 = $userIdme)
    OR (location_comments_b.statcom_uid = friend.userId2 AND friend.userId1 = $userIdme)
    WHERE friend.status1 = '1' AND friend.status2 = '1'
    OR location_comments_b.statcom_uid = '$userIdme'
    GROUP BY location_comments_b.id)
    ";

    $club_status = "
    (SELECT clubcomments.timestamp, clubcomments.id, clubcomments.com_uid, clubcomments.com_name, clubcomments.com_content, clubcomments.com_id, friend.userId1, friend.userId2, friend.status1, friend.status2,
    'clubcom' AS post_type FROM clubcomments
    LEFT JOIN friend
    ON (clubcomments.com_uid = friend.userId1 AND friend.userId2 = $userIdme)
    OR (clubcomments.com_uid = friend.userId2 AND friend.userId1 = $userIdme)
    WHERE friend.status1 = '1' AND friend.status2 = '1'
    OR clubcomments.com_uid = '$userIdme'
    GROUP BY clubcomments.id)
    ";

    $club_statcom = "
    (SELECT clubcomments_b.timestamp, clubcomments_b.id, clubcomments_b.statcom_uid, clubcomments_b.statcom_name, clubcomments_b.statcom_content, clubcomments_b.statcom_id, friend.userId1, friend.userId2, friend.status1, friend.status2,
    'clubstatcom' AS post_type FROM clubcomments_b
    LEFT JOIN friend
    ON (clubcomments_b.statcom_uid = friend.userId1 AND friend.userId2 = $userIdme)
    OR (clubcomments_b.statcom_uid = friend.userId2 AND friend.userId1 = $userIdme)
    WHERE friend.status1 = '1' AND friend.status2 = '1'
    OR clubcomments_b.statcom_uid = '$userIdme'
    GROUP BY clubcomments_b.id)
    ";

    $club_event = "
    (SELECT club_events.timestamp, club_events.fsid, club_events.usrida, club_events.author, club_events.content, club_events.subject, clubmem.userId1, clubmem.userId2, clubmem.status1, clubmem.status3,
    'clubevent' AS post_type FROM club_events
    LEFT JOIN clubmem
    ON (club_events.author = clubmem.userId1 AND clubmem.userId2 = $userIdme)
    WHERE clubmem.status2 = '1' AND clubmem.status3 = '1'
    OR club_events.usrida = '$userIdme'
    GROUP BY club_events.fsid)
    ";


        }else{
            $limitfriendstatus = "10"; 
        }

            $art_update = "
                (SELECT art.timestamp, art.id, art.usrida, art.name, art.type, art.title,
                    art.imgname, art.content1, art.vehicle_id, null,
                'art' AS post_type FROM art)";
            $club_update = "
                (SELECT club.timestamp, club.club_id, club.club_admin1, null, club.club_name, club.club_city,
                    club.club_state, club.club_about, club.club_privacy, null,
                'club' AS post_type FROM club)";
            $vp_update = "
                (SELECT submit.timestamp, submit.int, submit.usrida, submit.name, submit.color, submit.year,
                    submit.make, submit.model, submit.type, null,
                'submit' AS post_type FROM submit)";
            $vp_updateS = "
                (SELECT submit.timestamp, submit.int, submit.usrida, submit.name, submit.color, submit.year,
                    submit.make, submit.model, submit.type, null,
                'submit2' AS post_type FROM submit LIMIT 0)";

            if($rc_view){
                if($rc_view == "status"){ $query = "$vp_updateS UNION ALL $q_status UNION ALL $q_status_com ORDER BY timestamp DESC"; }
                if($rc_view == "sweets"){ $query = "$vp_updateS UNION $s_status ORDER BY timestamp DESC"; }
                if($rc_view == "comments"){ $query = "$vp_updateS UNION ALL $vpc_statcom UNION ALL $pc_statcom UNION ALL $pc_status UNION ALL $vpc_status UNION ALL $art_status UNION ALL $club_status UNION ALL $art_statcom UNION ALL $club_statcom UNION ALL $location_status UNION ALL $location_status_b ORDER BY timestamp DESC"; }
                if($rc_view == "clubs"){ $query = "$vp_updateS UNION ALL $club_update UNION ALL $club_event ORDER BY timestamp DESC"; }
                if($rc_view == "vehpro"){ $query = "$vp_updateS UNION $vp_update ORDER BY timestamp DESC"; }
                if($rc_view == "vehpic"){ $query = "$vp_updateS UNION $art_update ORDER BY timestamp DESC"; }
            }else{

                if(($userId = is_logged())!= 0)
                {
                $query = "
                    $vp_update UNION ALL
                    $club_update UNION ALL
                    $club_event UNION ALL
                    $art_update UNION ALL
                    $q_status UNION ALL
                    $q_status_com UNION ALL
                    $s_status UNION ALL
                    $pc_status UNION ALL
                    $vpc_status UNION ALL
                    $art_status UNION ALL
                    $club_statcom UNION ALL
                    $art_statcom UNION ALL
                    $pc_statcom UNION ALL
                    $vpc_statcom UNION ALL
                    $location_status UNION ALL
                    $location_status_b UNION ALL
                    $club_status 
                    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
                ";
                }else{
                $query = "
                    $vp_update UNION ALL
                    $club_update UNION ALL
                    $art_update
                    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
                ";
                }
            }

            $queryA = "$query LIMIT $limitfriendstatus";
            $queryB = "$query";

            $result = mysql_query($queryA)
                or die ("Couldn't ececute query. A");

            $result2 = mysql_query($queryB)
                or die ("Couldn't ececute query. B");

            $num_rows_posts = mysql_num_rows($result2);

                //Clean imgname string just in case its blank on a post
                unset($imgname);

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {

                    $bgcolor = "epboxa";

                extract($row);
    //echo "$usrida";
                //Testing timestamp
                $timestamp_p = $timestamp;
                //echo " ( timestamp = $timestamp_p ) ";

                if(isset($vm_id_a)){ $vm_id_a++; }else{ $vm_id_a = '1'; };

                echo "<a class='anchor' name='viewmore$vm_id_a'></a>";

                $color = stripslashes($color);
                $model = stripslashes($model);

                ////Vehicle Profile Start
                    if($post_type == "submit"){
                        require "pages/recentposts/rec_veh_pro.inc";
                    }
                ////Vehicle Profile End

                ////Club Start
                    if($post_type == "club"){
                        require "pages/recentposts/rec_club.inc";
                    }
                ////Club End

                ////Vehicle Pic Start
                    if($post_type == "art"){
                        require "pages/recentposts/rec_veh_pic.inc";
                    }
                ////Vehicle Pic End


                ////Status Start
                    if($post_type == "status"){
                        require "pages/recentposts/rec_status.inc";
                    }
                ////Status End

                ////Status Start
                    if($post_type == "statcom"){
                        require "pages/recentposts/rec_status_com.inc";
                    }
                ////Status End

                ////Sweet Start
                    if($post_type == "sweet"){
                        require "pages/recentposts/rec_sweet.inc";
                    }
                ////Sweet End

                ////Profile Comment Start
                    if($post_type == "profilecomment"){
                        require "pages/recentposts/rec_com_profile.inc";
                    }
                ////Profile Comment End

                ////Profile Comment comments Start
                    if($post_type == "profilestatcom"){
                        require "pages/recentposts/rec_com_profile_com.inc";
                    }
                ////Profile Comment comments End

                ////Vehicle Profile Comment Start
                    if($post_type == "vpcom"){
                        require "pages/recentposts/rec_com_vp.inc";
                    }
                ////Vehicle Profile Comment End

                ////Vehicle Profile Comment comment Start
                    if($post_type == "vpstatcom"){
                        require "pages/recentposts/rec_com_vp_com.inc";
                    }
                ////Vehicle Profile Comment comment End

                ////Vehicle Pic Comment Start
                    if($post_type == "artcom"){
                        require "pages/recentposts/rec_com_art.inc";
                    }
                ////Vehicle Pic Comment End

                ////Vehicle Pic Comment comments Start
                    if($post_type == "artstatcom"){
                        require "pages/recentposts/rec_com_art_com.inc";
                    }
                ////Vehicle Pic Comment comments End

                ////Club Comment Start
                    if($post_type == "clubcom"){
                        require "pages/recentposts/rec_com_club.inc";
                    }
                ////Club Comment End

                ////Club Comment comments Start
                    if($post_type == "clubstatcom"){
                        require "pages/recentposts/rec_com_club_com.inc";
                    }
                ////Club Comment comments End

                ////Club Event Start
                    if($post_type == "clubevent"){
                        require "pages/recentposts/rec_club_event.inc";
                    }
                ////Club Event End

                ////Location Comment Start
                    if($post_type == "loc_com"){
                        require "pages/recentposts/rec_com_locations.inc";
                    }
                ////Location Comment End

                ////Location Comment B Start
                    if($post_type == "loc_com_b"){
                        require "pages/recentposts/rec_com_locations_com.inc";
                    }
                ////Location Comment B End

                //Testing timestamp
                //echo " ( timestamp = $timestart ) <br>";

                            //Clean up vars
                            unset($timestart, $timestamp_p, $timestamp, $id, $int, $com_uid, $usrida, $com_name, $name, $com_content, $color, $com_id, $year);
                            unset($statfriend, $userId1, $userId2, $userId1a, $userId2a);
                            unset($sweet_location, $sweet_id, $sweet_userid, $sweet_url, $sweet_owner_userid);
                            unset($sw_usernameB, $sw_username, $sw_user_sweeted, $sw_username888, $sw_username88, $ID02, $timestart);
                            unset($com_uid, $com_id, $com_name, $com_content, $com_uid, $com_id, $com_name, $com_content );
                            //Clean imgname string just in case its blank on a post
                            unset($imgname);

            }  //End of main sql

        //Check to see if user is logged in and if there are later post they can view... then show link
        if(($userId = is_logged())!= 0)
        {
            $numofposts = $num_rows_posts;
            if(isset($vm_id_a)){}else{$vm_id_a = "0";}
            echo "Currently showing $vm_id_a of $numofposts posts.";//testing
            if( !isset($numofposts) ){$numofposts = "0";}else{
                //$plussome = ($num_rows - $numofposts);
                //echo "<Br>$limitfriendstatus - $num_rows - $numofposts - $plussome <br>";
                if(isset($num_rows)){}else{ $num_rows = ""; }
                if($limitfriendstatus < $num_rows || $limitfriendstatus < $numofposts){
                    $vm_id = $limitfriendstatus + 1;
                    echo "<table width=100%><tr><td>";
                    echo " <center><a href=\"?rc_view=$rc_view&offset=" . ($limitfriendstatus + 10) . "#viewmore$vm_id\">Show More Posts...</a> </center> "; 
                    echo "</td></tr></table><br><br>";
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: When I group by location_comments_b.statcom_id it only shows one comment but it's not the most recent.  I get an error when I try to order by location_comments_b.timestamp.

Comment: A WHERE clause on a LEFT JOINed table will generally render that join as an INNER JOIN - and what's with GROUP BY. I wish it could be banned

Comment: `Group By` in mysql should be fixed to force grouping by every non-aggregate column like it is in SQL Server. It is better to get an error than to successfully get back unexpected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the latest comment per location_comments_b.id, `JOIN` a `MAX(TimeStamp)` subquery:

```
SELECT
    b.timestamp, b.id, b.statcom_uid, b.statcom_name, b.statcom_content,
    b.statcom_id, f.userId1, f.userId2, f.status1, f.status2,
    'loc_com_b' AS post_type
FROM location_comments_b b
    JOIN (SELECT id,MAX(timestamp) timestamp
          FROM location_comments_b GROUP BY id) t
        ON t.id = b.id
        AND t.timestamp = b.timestamp
    LEFT JOIN friend f
        ON (b.statcom_uid = f.userId1 AND f.userId2 = $userIdme)
        OR (b.statcom_uid = f.userId2 AND f.userId1 = $userIdme)
    WHERE f.status1 = '1' AND f.status2 = '1'
        OR b.statcom_uid = '$userIdme'
```

Comment: No error with code but I get the same results as before and it shows all sub comment rows.  I added GROUP BY b.statcom_id and it only showed me one row.  However it did not show me the most recent row.

Comment: Ahh, it wasn't clear what your `location_comments_b` primary key was. It must be `id`? Is the `statcom_id` the foreign key related to the parent comment? Whatever that relationship is, that is what you want to group by.

Comment: Sweet.  I changed `id` to `statcom_id` and looks like a winner! @Ron Thanks a bunch.  Now the fun part of cleaning up my code and doing the same with all the other comments on the site.